# How is it possible for a dot to have no dimension, while a line can have 1 dimension?

Tags: geometry

In mathematics it is said that a "dot" has no dimension.
On a different context it is said that a line is made by joining different "dots".
Then how do line have only one dimension when its made up of something which has no dimension??

Comment: Since when was a line made up of just its two endpoints? The dimension $1$ stuff is what's in between.

Comment: @milo brandt....i know but how is it even getting that one dimension since its made up of "dots" which has no dimension......

Comment: Answering this question is mostly about resolving language: what is the definition of dimension you are working with?

Comment: I think itz upon us if we accdpt a dot to be  $dx$ circle then we can say it to 1D

Comment: How is it possible for "cat" to refer to a small, furry mammal, when neither "c" nor "a" nor "t" has any of those qualities by itself? It's an "emergent property". Put things together the right way, the collection can have properties that the individual components don't have.

Comment: How can the set of natural numbers be infinite when every element is finite?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need for this question to make sense is a definition of *dimension*. One convenient and commonly used notion is the [Hausdorff dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension). The definiton may be too technical and beyond the level you seem to be asking at, but here it is anyway: the Hausdorff dimension of a metric space (or say, a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$) is the smallest possible $d > 0$ such that your set can be covered with balls of radius $r_1, r_2, \ldots$, where the sum $\sum_{i} r_i^d$ is finite. (Actually, rather than "smallest possible", it's the infimum, in the case that there is no smallest $d$.)

Under this definition, it turns out that a point has Hausdorff dimension $0$ and a line has Hausdorff dimension $1$. How is this possible? Well, in your question, you seem to be assuming some principle like

> The union of any collection of sets of dimension $d$ must have dimension $d$.

Assuming "dimension" = "Hausdorff dimension", this is true for a *finite* union. It is even true for a countably infinite union. But a line is composed of *uncountably many* points, and in the case of an uncountable collection the principle above is simply false.